# Affiliate Performance Dashboard cumulating multiple Affiliate Networks from Australia and World

Tags: web-apps, business-intelligence, marketing

I'm looking for a KPI dashboard software to access all my efforts as a publisher with various affiliate networks in a single place.

Must have Affiliate Networks:

- Commission Factory
- APD Performance
- Rakuten Linkshare
- Clixgalore
- Impact Radius

Other requirements or features (nice to have)

- Ubuntu Desktop App
- Android App
- can be a Web-App, too

Any hints and links are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a startup for just this purpose: https://mydash.io.

It's completely free during beta so come and check it out :)

Unfortunately, I don't have all of your networks connected yet, but if you ping me on the inapp chat I'll try to connect the rest asap. It's demand and supply basically. :)

Cheers!